# Group rows by minimum value

Tags: python, r, dataframe

The problem is that I have some tables to build and some values are under an specific threshold. For example:

```
    S1  S2  S3
A   700 367 751
B   354 103 143
C   18  7   6
D   27  11  5
E   3   6   1
F   8   2   9
G   1   3   2
```

What I desire is to keep the rows where the values contain at least one value is equal or greater than 10 and merge the rows where the values are less than 10 to create a row named `"Other (<10)"`:

1 - Part of the table with rows with at least one cell containing one value greater than 10 (Row C; value 18):

```
    S1  S2  S3
A   700 367 751
B   354 103 143
C   18  7   6
```

2 - Part of the table where any value is greater than 10.

```
E   3   6   1
F   8   2   9
G   1   3   2
```

The final table would have the last row with the sum of the columns from E, F, and G, including the "Other(>10)" row name. Like this:

```
            S1  S2  S3
A           700 367 751
B           354 103 143
C           18  7   6
D           27  11  5
Other(<10)  12  11  12
```

Comment: A solution might begin with `apply(df,1,max)`

Comment: `filtered.df <- df [ apply(df, 1, function(x){all(x>10)}), ]` this will give you the first part. Then you can add sum of those less than 10.

Comment: @G5W or just df.max(1)

Comment: @EFT  I don't know that function - and my copy of R does not either.

Comment: @EFT that's python dude. Also my function should be `any` instead of `all`\

Comment: @Masoud, yep. It was tagged both, wasn't paying enough attention to that.

Comment: @Masoud in this way (X>10) I will reject the 10. So, x>=10 will work better?

Comment: Will you have rows without any value > 10 that will not be consecutive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in R solution:

```
filtered.df <-   rbind( df[ apply(df, 1, function(x){any(x>=10)}), ],
               colSums( df[ apply(df, 1, function(x){all(x< 10)}), ]))
```

And this would be the output:

```
> filtered.df

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] 
# [1,]  700  367  751 
# [2,]  354  103  143 
# [3,]   18    7    6 
# [4,]   27   11    5 
# [5,]   12   11   12
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(c(700, 354, 18, 27, 3, 8, 1, 367, 103, 7, 11, 6, 2, 3, 751, 143, 6, 5, 1, 9, 2), .Dim = c(7L, 3L))
```

---

**Update:** Including column and row names:

---

As OP asked, for the column-names and row-names this would be the data:

```
 df <- structure(c(700, 354, 18, 27, 3, 8, 1, 367, 103, 7, 11, 6, 2, 3, 751, 143, 6, 5, 1, 9, 2), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), c("s1", "s2", "s3")))
```

And then using the same solution above we'll get:

```
> filtered.df

#    s1  s2  s3 
# A 700 367 751 
# B 354 103 143 
# C  18   7   6 
# D  27  11   5 
#    12  11  12
```

Comment: Nice and concise!

Comment: That's true @Masoud but it eliminates the headers and row names. It would be interesting to keep them and create the "Other(<10)" row.

Comment: @FelipeLira No. I just didn't have the column names in my structured data. It does not affect row names or column names at all.

Comment: Ok, @Masoud . I will try include row names in your df example to check and further try with my data.

Comment: In this case
".Dimnames = list(    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), c("s1", "s2", "s3"))"
could be substituted by
".Dimnames = list( row.names, col.names)" if I look for a generic script?

Comment: @FelipeLira Idk what you mean. That's a way that I represented the data.frame. `row.names` and `col.names` return the row names and column names. There, I am defining them for the first time. If you have the data.frame (I think you should, that's your example), you don't need to make it. Just apply the solution on your data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in python:

```
data = ["700 367 751", "354 103 143", "18  7   6", "27  11  5", "3   6   1", "8   2   9", "1   3   2"]

new_data = [map(int, i.split()) for i in data]

final_data = []

extra_data = [0, 0, 0]

for i in new_data:
   if any(b >= 10 for b in i):
        final_data.append(i)

   else:
       extra_data = [extra_data[c]+b for c, b in enumerate(i)]

final_data.append(extra_data)

print final_data
```

Answer (score 2):

A Vectorized option for R would be,

```
ind <- rowSums(df > 10) == 0

rbind(df[!ind,], colSums(df[ind,]))

#   S1  S2  S3
#A 700 367 751
#B 354 103 143
#C  18   7   6
#D  27  11   5
#   12  11  12
```